# How to properly shadow tabs on a box shadow?

Tags: css, material-design, box-shadow

I'm trying correctly shadow the tabs on this site. Not sure If the issue are the values or the html markup.

```css
div.ui-tabs-panel.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-bottom {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px         rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

div.variableselector_valuesselect_variabletitle_panel {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


a.ui-tabs-anchor {
    box-shadow: 1px 4px 2px       rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 1px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
```

here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please, add what you'd expect to happen and also the HTML code of the part you're trying to get help for. If possible post a Snippet or a Fiddle of the form part you're trying to fix

Comment: I'll try to put something together. What I do whant is that the tabs whould be shadowed in a way they'd be part of the content shadow box). but II can't seem to set it right (the shadow in the tabs.

Comment: @user3431336 https://codepen.io/code_juice/pen/pmRbjN is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

[image]

```
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab"></div>
        <div class="tab"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
    </div>

.box-container{
  position: absolute;
  top:72px;
  left:4em;
  tansform: translate(0,-50%);
  height: 50%;
  width:60%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  z-index:0;
  background: #fff;
  filter:drop-shadow(2px 2px 5px #555)
}
.tabs{
  position: absolute;
  display:flex;
  left:4em;
  top:1.5em;
  justify-content: space-between;
   z-index:999;
}
.tab{
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom:0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 18px -5px #555;
  box-shadow: 18px 0 18px -5px #555;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 18px -5px #555;
  }
```